# Technology behind this book

Tags: microcontroller

https://youtu.be/yvNI5R65caU

Hi, I just came across this kind of book online, btw this book detects and reads out what are written in the cards. My question is how does it detect what is written in the card? Thanks

Comment: Web magic is not electrical or electronic engineering. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

You may notice that the "go" button is at different positions on every sheet and every side of the same sheet. This is how the electronic "knows" what page has been activated.

Based on this information it's very easy for the software to decide what sound to play when a certain instrument is pressed.

The technology behind may be a simple foil keyboard connected to some kind of IC reading that keyboard input and generating a sound to be output using a piezoelectric speaker. There's absolutely no witchcraft in it.